# Magento 2.4.3: Getting Error while reindexing

Tags: magento2, error, reindexing

I have got this error while running the magneto reindexing command, See attached screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/796hs.png, Please anyone has solution then help me

Comment: Make sure your elastic search is working

Comment: make sure elastic service are there and it should be active

Comment: It's activated and configured properly..Please check this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/UJEDK85.png

Comment: From admin can you please check test connection is successfully or not?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it returns successfully!!!